Filling a JSON array that can have a single element using JOLT V0.1.1
I am working on NiFi and I am wanting to do a JOLT V0.1.1 transformation that generates a JSON array from a JSON input. But I'm having the problem that, when the JSON comes with a single potential element for that array, the output is null. This is the transformation Este es uno de los inputs:
{
  "data": {
    "type": "applications",
    "id": "66g4cfcfc9efaad060007dda346b24",
    "attributes": {
      "appliedAt": 1716321481,
      "completedAt": 1716321566,
      "status": "new",
      "progress": {
        "all": 5,
        "completed": 5
      },
      "matchingScore": 12,
      "language": "en-GB",
      "matchingProfile": {
        "bracketId": "poor",
        "label": "Below B2"
      }
    }
  },
  "included": [
    {
      "type": "matching-indicators",
      "id": "65bd129c74158f00070d67d4",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "English Proficiency",
        "score": 12,
        "bracketId": "poor",
        "externalId": "",
        "fail": false,
        "label": "Below B2"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "matching-indicators",
      "id": "65bd1463de98c00007e0fa9d",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Situational Judgement Test",
        "score": 42,
        "bracketId": "good",
        "externalId": "",
        "fail": false,
        "label": "Good Fit",
        "brackets": [
          {
            "bracketId": "good",
            "cutoff": false,
            "name": "Good Fit",
            "treshold": 40
          },
          {
            "bracketId": "great",
            "cutoff": false,
            "name": "Great Fit",
            "treshold": 80
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

And this is the JOLT transformation that I was using to obtain an array with all the Matching Indicators information:
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "included": {
        "*": {
          "type": {
            "matching-indicators": {
              "@2": ""
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "attributes": {
          "name": "[&2].name",
          "label": "[&2].label",
          "score": "[&2].score"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

The output obtained was:
[
  {
    "name": "English Proficiency",
    "label": "Below B2",
    "score": 12
  },
  {
    "name": "Situational Judgement Test",
    "label": "Good Fit",
    "score": 42
  }
]

Which is exactly what I need for this case.
Now, when I have just one matching indicator in that input, I get a null output using the exact same JOLT. This is an example of an input with one matching indicator:
{
  "data": {
    "type": "applications",
    "id": "664cfcc9efaa0600rgd0798346b24",
    "attributes": {
      "appliedAt": 1716321481,
      "completedAt": 1716321566,
      "status": "new",
      "progress": {
        "all": 5,
        "completed": 5
      },
      "matchingScore": 12,
      "language": "en-GB",
      "matchingProfile": {
        "bracketId": "poor",
        "label": "Below B2"
      }
    }
  },
  "included": [
    {
      "type": "matching-indicators",
      "id": "65bd129c74skyt15h8f00070d67d4",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "English Proficiency",
        "score": 12,
        "bracketId": "poor",
        "externalId": "",
        "fail": false,
        "label": "Below B2"
      }
    }
  ]
}

I tried with this transformation too:
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "included": {
        "*": {
          "attributes": {
            "name": "[&1].name",
            "label": "[&1].label",
            "score": "[&1].score"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

And when I validated it at https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ it seems to work for both scenarios. But when I use it directly in NiFi, it gives me this kind of outputs for the second input:
[
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  {
    "name": "English Proficiency",
    "label": "Below B2",
    "score": 12
  }
]

How could I obtain the correct output? Is there at least any way to delete those 'null' elements in the same transformation?
This is actually the complete json input:
{
  "data": {
    "type": "applications",
    "id": "664caa6588bf5100078bb060",
    "attributes": {
      "appliedAt": 1716300389,
      "completedAt": 1716300607,
      "status": "new",
      "progress": {
        "all": 12,
        "completed": 12
      },
      "matchingScore": 48,
      "language": "en-GB",
      "matchingProfile": {
        "bracketId": "poor",
        "label": "Poor Fit"
      }
    },
    "relationships": {
      "candidate": {
        "data": {
          "type": "candidates",
          "id": "664caa6588bf5100078bb060",
          "email": "test.test+9@test.net",
          "attributes": {
            "firstName": "test",
            "lastName": "test",
            "email": "test.test+9@test.net"
          }
        }
      },
      "vacancy": {
        "data": {
          "type": "vacancies",
          "id": "65bd009dde98c00007e0e7b4"
        }
      },
      "report": {
        "data": {
          "type": "reports",
          "id": "17163006095testREPORT.pdf"
        }
      },
      "fact-sheets": {
        "data": {
          "type": "fact-sheets",
          "id": "1716300609489agtest_SHEET.pdf"
        }
      },
      "candidate-detail-page": {
        "data": {
          "type": "candidate-detail-page",
          "id": "664caa6588bf5100078bb060"
        }
      },
      "matching-results": {
        "data": [
          {
            "type": "matching-results",
            "id": "664caa6588bf5100078bb060-65bcfffd74158f00070d5a96"
          },
          {
            "type": "matching-results",
            "id": "664caa6588bf5100078bb060-65bd0023de98c00007e0e6a8"
          },
          {
            "type": "matching-results",
            "id": "664caa6588bf5100078bb060-65bd006cde98c00007e0e6fa"
          },
          {
            "type": "matching-results",
            "id": "664caa6588bf5100078bb060-65bd007f74158f00070d5b0f"
          },
          {
            "type": "matching-results",
            "id": "664caa6588bf5100078bb060-65c6263974b26da67537703d"
          }
        ]
      },
      "matching-indicators": {
        "data": [
          {
            "type": "matching-indicators",
            "id": "65bd128774158f00070d67bd"
          },
          {
            "type": "matching-indicators",
            "id": "65bd129c74158f00070d67d4"
          },
          {
            "type": "matching-indicators",
            "id": "65bd133fde98c00007e0fa12"
          },
          {
            "type": "matching-indicators",
            "id": "65bd1463de98c00007e0fa9d"
          }
        ]
      },
      "personal-information": {
        "data": {
          "type": "personal-information",
          "id": "65bcfff5de98c00007e0e64b"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "included": [
    {
      "type": "reports",
      "id": "171630060testREPORT.pdf",
      "attributes": {
        "expiresAt": 1716390988,
        "url": "https://ZGE4MGRmMmU2MmZhOGQzYmU1NmQ1MGFlMWZiMjhjM2Q3OGQ2NmUyM2M3NjQxZWI5ODY3Nzg1NzdlNDc0ZjM3/ENG/Y29tLmhhcnZlci50ZXN0LmludGVncmF0aW9uLnRyYW5zY29tZW1lYQ=="
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "fact-sheets",
      "id": "17163006094testT_SHEET.pdf",
      "attributes": {
        "expiresAt": 1716390988,
        "url": "https://e=20240522T150128Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Signature=c7429579e22e1f72efd57e60c9cd17510c389723ef12fe17659223b408ff3cc4&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "candidate-detail-page",
      "id": "664caa6588bf5100078bb060",
      "attributes": {
        "url": "https://sults/664caa6588bf5100078bb060"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "matching-results",
      "id": "664caa6588bf5100078bb060-65bcfffd74158f00070d5a96",
      "attributes": {
        "moduleType": "PersonalityPrintModule",
        "calculatedAt": 1716300607,
        "moduleScore": 0,
        "moduleWeight": 0
      },
      "relationships": {
        "module": {
          "data": {
            "type": "modules",
            "id": "65bcfffd74158f00070d5a96"
          }
        }
      },
      "meta": {
        "dimensionScores": {
          "agreeableness": {
            "percentile": 5.7,
            "rawScore": 3.5
          },
          "assertiveness": {
            "percentile": 91.14,
            "rawScore": 4.333333333333333
          },
          "empathy": {
            "percentile": 23.9,
            "rawScore": 4.125
          },
          "followThrough": {
            "percentile": 61.3,
            "rawScore": 5
          },
          "learningFocused": {
            "percentile": 81.05,
            "rawScore": 5
          },
          "multitasking": {
            "percentile": 18,
            "rawScore": 3
          },
          "organization": {
            "percentile": 0.01,
            "rawScore": 2.25
          },
          "preferenceForDirection": {
            "percentile": 0.01,
            "rawScore": 2.25
          },
          "resilience": {
            "percentile": 77.82,
            "rawScore": 5.166666666666667
          },
          "sociability": {
            "percentile": 84.81,
            "rawScore": 5
          },
          "workIntensity": {
            "percentile": 4.3,
            "rawScore": 3.142857142857143
          }
        },
        "normGroup": "europe",
        "variant": "short"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "matching-results",
      "id": "664caa6588bf5100078bb060-65bd0023de98c00007e0e6a8",
      "attributes": {
        "moduleType": "NOAModule",
        "calculatedAt": 1716300607,
        "moduleScore": 0,
        "moduleWeight": 0
      },
      "relationships": {
        "module": {
          "data": {
            "type": "modules",
            "id": "65bd0023de98c00007e0e6a8"
          }
        }
      },
      "meta": {
        "components": [
          {
            "normGroup": "medium",
            "score": 0,
            "type": "NOA Exclusion"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "matching-results",
      "id": "664caa6588bf5100078bb060-65bd006cde98c00007e0e6fa",
      "attributes": {
        "moduleType": "LanguageTestModule",
        "calculatedAt": 1716300607,
        "moduleScore": 16.333333333333332,
        "moduleWeight": 0
      },
      "relationships": {
        "module": {
          "data": {
            "type": "modules",
            "id": "65bd006cde98c00007e0e6fa"
          }
        }
      },
      "meta": {
        "grading": "<B2",
        "sectionScores": [
          {
            "name": "vocabulary",
            "score": 13
          },
          {
            "name": "grammar",
            "score": 20
          },
          {
            "name": "comprehension",
            "score": 16
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "matching-results",
      "id": "664caa6588bf5100078bb060-65bd007f74158f00070d5b0f",
      "attributes": {
        "moduleType": "JobKnowledgeTestModule",
        "calculatedAt": 1716300607,
        "moduleScore": 0,
        "moduleWeight": 0
      },
      "relationships": {
        "module": {
          "data": {
            "type": "modules",
            "id": "65bd007f74158f00070d5b0f"
          }
        }
      },
      "meta": {
        "scoresByQuestionId": {
          "0daeeeb4-eabd-4b64-9f0f-7d01fb09bf08": 0,
          "2dba74a2-d527-4c65-a734-2d6017355ac3": 0,
          "3bbe3045-6a74-463a-8242-8f8b1ae778c7": 0,
          "3db7a0c7-0027-4836-8208-475e41009d56": 0,
          "613592b8-6b95-4e55-ac87-2dc3d08f92c7": 0,
          "68a710b6-ac2b-4986-90e2-5d14695d3405": 0,
          "6c331725-12f0-4ebd-8282-37a1361771d8": 0,
          "8156b45b-6c4f-469d-8698-902e6cc12400": 0,
          "8a1c0138-3f57-42d0-bbf7-4c6f577ab5a9": 0,
          "bee5f06f-7353-4de7-b078-4ce17fa58542": 0
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "matching-results",
      "id": "664caa6588bf5100078bb060-65c6263974b26da67537703d",
      "attributes": {
        "moduleType": "SituationalJudgmentTestModule",
        "calculatedAt": 1716300607,
        "moduleScore": 41.66666666666667,
        "moduleWeight": 0
      },
      "relationships": {
        "module": {
          "data": {
            "type": "modules",
            "id": "65c6263974b26da67537703d"
          }
        }
      },
      "meta": {
        "pointsPerQuestion": {
          "026c7707-7f0e-43ef-bfc0-c165f6a1e5e2": {
            "points": -1,
            "score": 25
          },
          "5a4922e4-b15d-4e5f-9fb7-566ee88b7a9c": {
            "points": 1,
            "score": 75
          },
          "a0052eaa-fc4f-4235-b5d4-77209c79e0db": {
            "points": -1,
            "score": 25
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "ats-parameters",
      "attributes": {
        "candidateId": "395303",
        "jobId": "893",
        "createdBy": "api"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "matching-indicators",
      "id": "65bd128774158f00070d67bd",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Logical Reasoning",
        "score": 0,
        "bracketId": "poor",
        "externalId": "",
        "fail": false,
        "label": "Poor Fit",
        "brackets": [
          {
            "bracketId": "good",
            "cutoff": false,
            "name": "Good Fit",
            "treshold": 40
          },
          {
            "bracketId": "great",
            "cutoff": false,
            "name": "Great Fit",
            "treshold": 66
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "matching-indicators",
      "id": "65bd129c74158f00070d67d4",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "English Proficiency",
        "score": 16,
        "bracketId": "poor",
        "externalId": "",
        "fail": false,
        "label": "Below B2",
        "brackets": [
          {
            "bracketId": "good",
            "cutoff": false,
            "name": "B2 and above",
            "treshold": 66
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "matching-indicators",
      "id": "65bd133fde98c00007e0fa12",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Customer Support Personality V2TEST",
        "score": 57,
        "bracketId": "poor",
        "externalId": "",
        "fail": false,
        "label": "Poor Fit",
        "brackets": [
          {
            "bracketId": "good",
            "cutoff": false,
            "name": "Good Fit",
            "treshold": 65
          },
          {
            "bracketId": "great",
            "cutoff": false,
            "name": "Great Fit",
            "treshold": 80
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "matching-indicators",
      "id": "65bd1463de98c00007e0fa9d",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Situational Judgement Test",
        "score": 42,
        "bracketId": "good",
        "externalId": "",
        "fail": false,
        "label": "Good Fit",
        "brackets": [
          {
            "bracketId": "good",
            "cutoff": false,
            "name": "Good Fit",
            "treshold": 40
          },
          {
            "bracketId": "great",
            "cutoff": false,
            "name": "Great Fit",
            "treshold": 80
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

And I am obtaining this output:
[ null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, {
  "name" : "Logical Reasoning",
  "score" : 0,
  "label" : "Poor Fit"
}, {
  "name" : "English Proficiency",
  "score" : 16,
  "label" : "Below B2"
}, {
  "name" : "Customer Support Personality V2TEST",
  "score" : 57,
  "label" : "Poor Fit"
}, {
  "name" : "Situational Judgement Test",
  "score" : 42,
  "label" : "Good Fit"
} ]


The problem is due to missing square brackets for the key-value pair nested within "matching-indicators" object, that should be : "@2": "[]" instead of "@2": "".
eg use :
"matching-indicators": {
  "@2": "[]"
}

That technique is mostly used for the sake of single objects nested within an array, and doesn't lead a problem for the multiple objects nested within an array as well.
Indeed, only one shift transformation spec would handle the issue(for both cases) such as
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "included": {
        "*": {
          "type": {
            "matching-indicators": {
              "@2,attributes": {
                "name|score|label": "[&4].&"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

Demo for Case 1 ( on https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ ) :

Demo for Case 2 :


Hi Barbaros! I used that shift but I still have the same problem. The output I got is the next one:
[ null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, {   "name" : "Logical Reasoning",   "score" : 0,   "label" : "Poor Fit" }, {   "name" : "English Proficiency",   "score" : 16,   "label" : "Below B2" }, {   "name" : "Customer Support Personality V2TEST",   "score" : 57,   "label" : "Poor Fit" }, {   "name" : "Situational Judgement Test",   "score" : 42,   "label" : "Good Fit" } ]

Can you please check out the added demoes @MarianoBaudena

thanks for your answer, the same thing happens as with the transformation that I had created. It works fine in the demo but fills the array with null elements when I apply it to our framework. It's weird, because it uses the same version of JOLT. It occurs to me that if there was some way to explicitly exclude null elements from an array it could be solved, but I don't know if this is an option.

I think I found the problem. I had published a summarized version of the json so that whoever sees it can focus only on those fields, but the problem occurs when I use the original json. I just added the complete json input to the original question @BarbarosÖzhan

I did now :) I think I will create another question with the correct information. Thanks Barbaros!
